# Using DJI mavic min in Iceland during July

Tags: regulations

I was wondering if someone had the chance to fly a DJI mavic mini/2 in Iceland?

Im asking because it is small and im not so familiar with drones, all I read is that it can fly up to 13/16 m/s winds but of course nothing can beat experienced answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drone regulations for Iceland can be found [here](https://www.icetra.is/aviation/drones/) and [here (full PDF)](https://www.icetra.is/media/log-og-reglur-i-flugmalum/Regulation-990-2017-on-the-operation-of-remotely-piloted-aircraft.pdf); they include an [FAQ](https://www.icetra.is/aviation/drones/frequently-asked-questions-faq/) which suggests recreational use is permitted - I have quoted a few of the points below, but I recommend you check their site for full details:

> **Do I need formal training and/or licence to fly a drone?**
> There is no requirement for special training/licence to fly drones under 25 kg, provided they are used for recreational purposes.
> ...
> **Is it mandatory to register the drone?**
> Recreational flights: No need to register.
> ...
> **Is insurance for drones mandatory?**
> ...
> Recreational use: Insurance is not mandatory.
> ...
> **Where are drones prohibited?**
>
> - Over a crowd of people
> - Close to airports with scheduled traffic
> - Close to private houses and public buildings
> - Above 120 meters
> - Beyond visual line of sight of the pilot (BVLOS)
>
> ...
> **Can I fly over National Parks?**
> For flying over National Parks you need to apply for a permit...

As to the safe wind speed for operating a DJI aircraft, you should check the specifications of your drone on the DJI website; look for the "Max Wind Speed Resistance" number on the "Specs" page (e.g. [DJI Mini 2](https://www.dji.com/uk/mini-2/specs).)